# Show year in x axis labels in timePlot() function

Tags: r, openair

I found one relevant question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43898572/how-change-the-scale-and-labels-in-scatterplot-of-the-openair-package-of-r), but my story is different. Using R OpenAir package, I am trying to create some beautiful timeseries plots (time period: December 2014 - May 2015). Here is the code:

```
timePlot(data, pollutant=c("NO_predicted", "NO_modelled"), group = TRUE, cols=c("blue", "red"),
         data.thresh = 0, xlab="Year", ylab="Observed and Predicted NO", 
         lty=c(1, 1), lwd=c(1, 1), xlim = as.POSIXct(c("2014-12-01", "2015-05-31")))
```

This is how the plot looks like:

[image]

I want to make it more beautiful by adding years in the x-axis labels. For example, `Dec-14`, `Jan-15`, `Feb-15` and so on.

Can someone suggest how to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the documentation of `timePlot`. There are two options that are of interest to you:

> **date.breaks** Number of major x-axis intervals to use. The function will try and choose a sensible number of dates/times as well as
>   formatting the date/time appropriately to the range being considered.
>   This does not always work as desired automatically. The user can
>   therefore increase or decrease the number of intervals by adjusting
>   the value of date.breaks up or down.
>
> **date.format** This option controls the date format on the x-axis. While timePlot generally sets the date format sensibly there can be
>   some situations where the user wishes to have more control. For format
>   types see strptime. For example, to format the date like “Jan-2012”
>   set date.format = "%b-%Y".